# "Describe (Pandas)" multiple variables as one variable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this data-frame with variables `X1` - `X5`:

```
 X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
 14  52   2  76  81
 42  15  86  79  52
 40  96  90  87  51
 74  99   8  75  95
 40  25  52  16  24
 74  58  91   2   9
 56   5   6  36  37
 85  65  17   4   2
 88   6  42  19  11
  3   5  84  33  56
```

I want to use the `describe()` function (Pandas) treating those five variables as a one variable.

Expected result:

```
               X
count  50.000000
mean   45.300000
std    32.567826
min     2.000000
25%    14.250000
50%    42.000000
75%    75.750000
max    99.000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `df.values.flatten()` to get the entire data into one column:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df.values.flatten(),columns=['X']).describe()
               X
count  50.000000
mean   45.300000
std    32.567826
min     2.000000
25%    14.250000
50%    42.000000
75%    75.750000
max    99.000000
```

Or, more easily:

```
>>> df.stack().describe()
               
count  50.000000
mean   45.300000
std    32.567826
min     2.000000
25%    14.250000
50%    42.000000
75%    75.750000
max    99.000000
```

But you will not get the column name as `X` in this case.

References:

1. [`df.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)
2. [`np.array.flatten()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)
3. [`df.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `melt` for that following way (for simplicity I use data with less numbers):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X1':[14,42,40],'X2':[52,15,96],'X3':[2,86,90]})
print(df.melt()['value'].describe())
```

Output:

```
count     9.000000
mean     48.555556
std      35.330975
min       2.000000
25%      15.000000
50%      42.000000
75%      86.000000
max      96.000000
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Explanation: `.melt` of DataFrame when used without arguments result in two-column DataFrame with `variable`s and `value`s. First is name of column from which given value is taken, second is just that value. For `df` from my example `print(df.melt())` gives:

```
  variable  value
0       X1     14
1       X1     42
2       X1     40
3       X2     52
4       X2     15
5       X2     96
6       X3      2
7       X3     86
8       X3     90
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.concat([df[x] for x in df]).describe()
```

should do the trick. All the answers in this post will work but this one would be the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `reshape`:

```
pd.Series(df.values.reshape(-1)).describe()
```

result:

```
count    50.000000
mean     45.300000
std      32.567826
min       2.000000
25%      14.250000
50%      42.000000
75%      75.750000
max      99.000000
dtype: float64
```